# Changing prompt text for JavaFX textfield

Tags: javafx, textfield

I have a choicebox and textfield next to that choicebox in a JavaFX application. I want grey textbox in the textfield to tell the user what to input. However, I want the prompt text to change according to what is selected in the choicebox.

I looked online and found code on how to have a textfield with prompt text but I couldn't get the prompt text to change with a changeListener on the choicebox.

I tried

```
textfield = new Textfield(newPrompt);
```

with the textfield already previously declared with a different prompt text. This did not work. How do I achieve the effect of having changing prompt text based on the users selection in the choicebox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reassigning the `textfield` variable to a new `TextField` object (via `textfield = new TextField(newPrompt);`), use the TextField's `setPromptText(String s)` method in your ChangeListener:

```
final ChoiceBox<String> box = ...; //choicebox created and filled

box.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            textfield.setPromptText("New Prompt Text!");
        }
    });
```